# Flex container does not wrap around the width of image (not working in Safari/Firefox)

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, carousel

I have the desired layout working in Chrome (mac OS) but I've checked Safari/Firefox and I don't get the same result.

Link (and code below): https://codepen.io/moy/pen/NWaObyW

You can see here if I remove the image it's more consistent. But the image ignores the parent height: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/VwMqzQv

**EDIT**
So I kinda got it working but I don't understand why the parent (in Firefox/Safari) is so wide? It's like it's taking the height of the image before 'object-fit'? https://codepen.io/moy/pen/JjrwrJR

I have a container that is 100% (or vh) of the browser. Within the container there are two div's where 'main' content is displayed and a 'footer' that is fixed to the bottom. The 'main' content above the footer should fill the remaining height (no fixed values). As this is an image, I don't want it to cover the horizontal space or have a max-width.

The declaration that Chrome seems to be acknowledging that other browsers aren't is `overflow: hidden` which makes the `img` fit vertically within the container.

It's worth nothing the image will be several going forward, in a simple fading slideshow/carousel.

Really appreciate some help on this! I've tried lots of different `flex` declarations and extra divs but I haven't found a solution yet - in Chrome at least.

Here are some images of how it should look/behave as well. Extreme examples (short vh) just to illustrate.

**Taller viewport:**

[image: Taller viewport height]

**Shorter viewport:**

[image: Shorter viewport height]

**Embed Code:**

```css
html {
    background: white;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: white;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

/**
 * Base `body` styling.
 */

body {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures discretionary-ligatures historical-ligatures;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.grid__item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 24px 24px 0;
}

.gallery {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    
    .grid {
        background-color: black;
        display: grid;
        grid-column-gap: 2px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .grid__item {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        grid-column: span 6;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .gallery {
        display: flex;
        align-self: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
  
  .gallery img {
    height: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
  }
    
    /* img {
        object-fit: contain;
        max-height: none;
    } */
    
    .grid__item-footer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-top: auto;
    }
    
    .grid__item-footer .gallery-count {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 0%;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid__item">

    <h1 class="brand-name">Brand Name</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <p class="grid__item-footer">Footer Item</span></p>
  </div>

  <div class="grid__item">

    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/600/850" />
    </div>

    <p class="grid__item-footer">Name of Project <span class="gallery-count">1 / 8</span></p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am getting the same result in edge and firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKzXU.jpg the image is the same, is resizes herself if is a not taller screen like you want... maybe is my error because I didn't understand the question, can you pls tell me what is wrong (for example the element need to be bigger, etc)? sorry if I want more info

Comment: That's fine but if you make the screen wider so there's white space either side of the image - that's when it'll start to break I think!

Comment: also now I see, yes there is whitespace but because is centered, and is the same result in both EDGE https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUs9.png and FIREFOX https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyROu.png (i didn't understand, sorry another time for this) in my case I have the latest version of edge and firefox browsers, maybe is something about compatibility, I don't know... I tried to do my best

Comment: No probs - appreciate it! So basically in those screenshots the image should be taller/stretch to the bottom - or as close as possible in the space.